# Python Turtle: How can I make the outline of a text black and the fill white?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is what I've got so far.

```
turtle = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

turtle.goto(-200, -300)

turtle.write("Hello World", move=False, align="left", font=("Candara", 30, "normal"))
```

How can I make the outline of this text black and the fill white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, honestly. A pretty cheap workaround is to select a monospaced font (like Deja Vu Sans Mono) and to print in two layers like this

```
turtle.write("Hello World", move=False, align="left", font=("Deja Vu Sans Mono", 30, "bold"))
turtle.color("white")
turtle.write("Hello World", move=False, align="left", font=("Deja Vu Sans Mono", 30, "normal"))
```

Here, the first layer is black and has bold letters, the second one is white and uses a normal font. This will only yield a small outline on the vertical edges of the letters, not on the horizontal ones as the font preserves its height when set to bold.

Comment: Not what I was expecting but turns out it's a pretty decent solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Until we figure out the right way to do this, if there is one, let's simulate an outline font:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

STRING = "Hello World!"

FONT_SIZE = 60
DELTA_SIZE = 2
FONT = ("Ariel", FONT_SIZE, "normal")
OUTLINE_FONT = ("Ariel", FONT_SIZE + 2 * DELTA_SIZE, "bold")

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

X, Y = -100, -300

turtle.goto(X, Y)

for letter in STRING:
    turtle.color('black')
    oldx = turtle.xcor()
    turtle.write(letter, move=True, align="left", font=OUTLINE_FONT)
    newx = turtle.xcor()

    turtle.color(screen.bgcolor())
    turtle.setposition(oldx + (newx - oldx) // 2, Y + DELTA_SIZE)
    turtle.write(letter, align="center", font=FONT)
    turtle.setposition(newx, Y)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

This realigns letter by letter and works with a variable pitch font as well as a monospaced font.  (Not well, just as well.)  @Solvalou's solution above mine in Courier 60 (monospaced font):

[image]

It comes down to taste and how much effort you want to put into the problem.